# Need help restoring my Wordpress blog

Tags: plugins, database

I installed wp-cache to help with site speed. Shortly afterward, I was unable to access the site. Included below are the browser errors I receive. The site is hosted by GoDaddy. I asked them to restore my site from a nightly backup, which they tried to do but it did not work. They recommended I reinstall Wordpress and restore the database from a backup. I did both but the only database I have to backup is from today, after the problem started. I'm no expert regarding databases but if you are restoring a bad database, the site still going to have problems, right?

I researched wp-cache plugin problems and found solutions that worked for some but not for me. Maybe the problem is not coming from the plugin. But my site is completely down. I need help. Desperation set in a long time ago.

Here's the error when visiting the home page:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: wp()

Error when visiting /wp-admin
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: get_option()

Error when visiting /wpadmin/upgrade.php
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: timer_start()

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the wp-cache folder? I had a bad update of a different plugin once and simply "uninstalling" it by removing it from the wp-content/plugins folder allowed things to run normally and I installed an older version of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring a bad database would reintroduce whatever problems you had with that database. However the errors you've include sound like your install of WordPress has missing/corrupt files. I'd recommend you try deleting all the WordPress files (except the `wp-content` directory and `wp-config.php`) from your site, then reinstall WordPress. If you're still getting these errors after doing so, download a fresh copy of WordPress, delete the WordPress files from your site and upload the fresh copies.